# Where is the watch window located in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Currently I'm using the Community version of Visual Studio and having trouble finding the Watch Window or its equivalent. In previous versions of Express studio there was the option to open the Watch Window in the Debug dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

The Watch, Local, Auto, and all Debug related windows will only appear in the menu if the debugger is currently debugging a program. This has been changed in Visual Studio 2013.

1. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to start debugging.
2. Debug → Windows → Auto / Local / Watch

That's all you need to do.

Comment: What an ugly decision. (Of course, my annoyance relates only to MS and not to your answer; thanks for your answer.)

Answer (score 7):

I think that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> will bring up the Watch window (default key bindings). Menu wise it is located under Debug→Windows→Watch→4 options listed

Check out this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290869%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) article for more info.